# count contando errado?

Tags: php, php-7

Tenho a seguinte chamada a uma **função**:

```
$exitente = $membrosDao->pesquisaMembrosNasFuncoes( $_POST[ "idMembro" ] );
```

Que para as requisições abaixo

```
print "<pre>";
print count($existente)."<br />";
print_r($exitente);
print "</pre>";
```

me entrega o seguinte resultado :

```
0
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idMembro] => 2
            [nomeTabela] => pastores
        )

)
```

Onde estou errando? Se o `array` possui 1 **retorno** porque o `count` está *retornando* **0**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O count está retornando zero porque o nome da variável está errado.

Observe na primeira chamada:

```
$exitente = $membrosDao->pesquisaMembrosNasFuncoes( $_POST[ "idMembro" ] );
```

O nome da variável é `$exitente`

E logo em seguida você printa `$existente`

Como a variável `$existente` não possui valor, retorna 0.

Comment: obrigado. Falta de atenção.